# SSRS 2016 - Change CSS of Report Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I want to change the css file of my reports.
How can I do it with reporting services 2016?
The old methods didn't work for me (add style sheet file or make changes at the HtmlViewer file).

Answer (score 0):

To just hide the headers and the option to navigate back to home change the link address to the report from

```
http://Reportserver/Reports_Instance/report/Folder/Report
```

to

```
http://Reportserver/ReportServer_Instance/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Folder/Report
```

So you only get to see the report

Answer (score -1):

To change the style of your report, it is intuitive. You can select the colors you want to include, chart borders, chart styles, etc directly on the GUI. I highly suggest that you rephrase your question to be more specific. Then, we can help you get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Hi my question is how can I change the css file.It is important for me to disappear some headers.

Comment: Can you provide a visual of what you're talking about, please? What headers do you want to disappear? As far as I know, in SSRS 2016, you can only have one header. This header is manually created or removed.

Comment: I don't succeed to upload image to the comments.But I want to hide the headers and the option to navigate back to home.I want the user will see only the report.

Comment: I think you're confusing the actual report itself with the SSRS application. Here is a good guide for you to review that may help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt710551.aspx#create

Comment: It doesn't help ,because I want to hide some parts of the reprots like the option to navigate home.The article explains only the way to change the colors of the reports and to hide parts if it.